# Twitter Product Card - Multiple Pages

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I have a product which has 3 pages:

> http://www.example.com/myproduct
>
> http://www.example.com/myproduct/more
>
> http://www.example.com/myproduct/images

I want to add a product twitter card:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="card">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@mytwitter">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My Product Title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Product Description goes here...">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.example.com/myproduct">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.example.com/product.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:data1" content="$3">
<meta name="twitter:label1" content="PRICE">
<meta name="twitter:data2" content="San Franscisco, CA">
<meta name="twitter:label2" content="LOCATION">
```

What I want to achieve is that the product image, description, price, and location should be shown from all 3 pages when the user shares any of the pages.

My questions is how can I achieve this, and is it better to use `<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.example.com/myproduct">` for all 3 pages, or use the canonical url of each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display the same [Product Card](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/types/product-card) for any of the three pages of your product, all you have to do is simply making sure you provide the same markup tags on all of them.

In fact, you don't even have to specify any `twitter:url` tag in Twitter Cards. The URL the user will be redirected to when clicking is automatically the one that has been shared in the Tweet.

Comment: Construction of the product card ... OK
So if I specify the twitter:url as the main product page, will it not redirect to that? (This is what I want)
I read somewhere that the twitter:url has been deprecated. But will it not override the default page if specified?

Comment: That is correct. The `twitter:url` will not be taken into account, the Product Card will redirect to the page being shared in the Tweet. Have you thought about encouraging people to Tweet the main product URLs by using [Tweet Buttons](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) on your pages with the links you would like them to share?

Comment: Yes I am using the tweet button, Facebook like button, Facebook share, and G+ button. Page load is getting slower though, I might need to do some debugging... Thanks for all the info.